# How to configure roles hierarchy (permission inheritance) in Strapi?

Tags: permissions, roles, policy, strapi, user-roles

I created resources in Strapi and selected access to find them for the public role. As I can expect I can receive a list of these resources sending a simple GET request:

```
http http://localhost:1337/objects
```

But when the user is logged in, I have attached the `Authorization` header and for a request:

```
http GET localhost:1337/objects Authorization:"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTUsImlhdCI6MTYwMDM3ODA3MiwiZXhwIjoxNjAyOTcwMDcyfQ.LL7YyZLGmBE32yAUi6SzGX7vbNNEdZKP8Wssu6vRZHs"
```

I have got

```
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "statusCode": 403
}
```

I know that I can fix it configuring access in the admin panel, but I would like to allow all public request tor authorized users by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need  Authorization:"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTUsImlhdCI6MTYwMDM3ODA3MiwiZXhwIjoxNjAyOTcwMDcyfQ.LL7YyZLGmBE32yAUi6SzGX7vbNNEdZKP8Wssu6vRZHs", if you configure public find , findOne

Comment: I agree, that no need authorization, but if user is logged in `Authorization` header is added by default to all request in fronted. I am asking how can I treat authorized user like public by inheritance of roles in strapi.